# OpenVPN timeout to reconnect on fail takes a long time

Tags: openvpn, high-availability

I'm trying to create a high-availability environment for my OpenVPN servers. I do this by having two identical VPN servers and in my client config specify multiple remote's:

```
# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote vpn1 1194
remote vpn2 1194

remote-random
```

This seem to work. I have a Vagrant environment with two VPN servers and two clients. Once the network runs and I stop OpenVPN on one of the VPN server the other server takes over.

However, before the other server takes over there is a long time before it actually does this. If my clients ping each other it takes about 3 minutes before the pinging continues. My guess is that the clients are trying to reconnect and that the time out is the issue here.

In my OpenVPN `client.conf` I have played with the following settings but it doesn't seem to make any difference (yes, I restart OpenVPN on the clients after changing the config):

```
connect-retry 2
connect-retry-max 2
```

How can I adjust the connect time out on the clients to make them switch faster to a different OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keepalive directive controls this:

```
# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120
```

Comment: Great. For those wondering, it's in the `server.conf`. I didn't spot it until now. Thanks!